# Is there a way for permanent lease of auth tocken in One Drive

Tags: oauth, dropbox, onedrive

I'm writing a small C++ console client to store configs (few megs) in a cloud. 
I try to minimize using non opensource code due to security reasons.
One Drive looks good to me. However they only want OAuth and lease token for one hour. There are 2 problems with this: 
1. I need to start webserver to serve redirects so it won't be small.
2. User should open browser and allow access on startup which is UX hell

Is there any way to permanently give access to app to store things in  drive

I tried Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, Yandex Disk. It seems all of them wither want me to OAuth.  I also think about using hosting services (github, bitbucket), but not sure they'll be happy with me bombarding them with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yandex disk leases token for ~1 year, and it also has option of showing access token to user instead of calling endpoint which eliminates need to start a server.